# Email Validation Using REGEX in a Controller Extension

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am writing a controller extension to intake data from a form to create cases. You can save and submit the form, but an Invalid Email Error is thrown when it tries to create the case and the email is not valid. below is an excerpt from the form where email is being input:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Case" extensions="PartnerSupportCaseController">
```

```
<apex:inputText required="true" value="{!Case.SuppliedEmail}" label="Email"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I am trying to Display an "Invalid Email" message when this is thrown (Using REGEX), and to process the rest of my Page Reference Save method if the email is valid. Below is the controller, where I have created a method using REGEX to validate the email, and then integrated that with "if (!checkEmail(sEmail))" after the Page Reference Save:

```
public class PartnerSupportCaseController {

public Case supportCase {get;set;}

public Attachment attachedFile;

private static Boolean isThereFile = True;

public Boolean sEmail;

public PartnerSupportCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

    this.supportCase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    supportCase.Protocol_Sub_Issue__c = 'Partner Support - Please Pick';
    supportCase.Protocol_Issue__c = 'Partner Support - Please Pick';
    supportCase.RecordTypeId = '012M000000092ju';

}

public Attachment getAttachedFile(){
    attachedFile = New Attachment();
    return attachedFile;

}

public  Boolean checkEmail (String sEmail) {
    String InputEmail = supportCase.SuppliedEmail;
    String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})';
    Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);

    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(InputEmail);

    if (!MyMatcher.matches()) {
        return false;
        }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}



public pagereference Save()
{
    if (!checkEmail(sEmail))
    {        
    upsert supportCase;


    Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = supportCase.Id, name = attachedFile.Name, body = attachedFile.Body);    
    String t = supportCase.Subject + ' (File Attached)';

    if (attachedFile.Body == null ){
        isThereFile = false;
    }
    else{
        supportCase.Subject = t;
        upsert supportCase;
        insert a; 

        }

    PageReference pg = Page.PartnerSupportThankYou;
    pg.setredirect(true);

    return pg;      
    }

        else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(New ApexPages.Message(ApexPAges.severity.Error, 'Please enter a valid email address'));
        }   


}


}
```

I keep getting an error in the console that "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: check email(Boolean)," however, I have created this method in the class here. Any input would go a long way, thank you

Best,
-CP

Comment: Have you tried changing the variable name to something like input_email, instead of using the exact same name as the context variable in your method? This might be causing Salesforce to misunderstand your code, thinking that you are calling a method that receives a boolean instead of a string (and the method that receives a boolean doesn't exist).

Comment: Hm, did you mean changing the sEmail variable? I tried changing String Input Email = supportCase.SuppliedEmail so that it can be matching the email input on the form (editing that in the question)

Comment: Yes, I mean the sEmail variable. But it doesn't matter if it is being used in the context (even after your edit) because it is confusing the compiler because you declared one with the same name in the beginning as a Boolean (public Boolean sEmail). Change that to "input_email" or something, along with its references, but leave the "sEmail" in your method unchanged.

Comment: Just to be annoying, that does not allow anywhere near all valid email addresses.  It doesn't even account for many TLDs.  And I think the `(\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)` matches domains that start with literally `[a-z]`.... which is invalid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkEmail` method accepts "String" parameter, but you are passing it a "Boolean". Declare your sEmail as String and then try again.

```
public  Boolean checkEmail (String sEmail) {
    Boolean returnValue = true;
    String InputEmail = supportCase.SuppliedEmail;
    String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})';
    Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);

    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(InputEmail);

    if (!MyMatcher.matches()) {
        returnValue = false;
        }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This was helpful, but now in th elast "else" statement, there states that a non-void method might not return a value or might have a statement after a return. I can mark this as the answer, but I just want to determine why this is the case, since I have this as the last statement in the code.

Comment: Edited my answer